# How to run both Angular4 & Angular6 Projects on my machine?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My Global Angular-CLI version is : 6.1.1 (Using which I can run Angular 6 projects Easily)
I have another project for Angular4 for which has CLI Version locally as :1.2.7

So when I try to run Angular4 project I get following error:

[image]

Comment: Try downgrading to v 6.0.8 globally. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11661

Comment: @David: thanks for your inpu ts

Comment: Have you tried  installing npm packages locally. You can have a local and global version of angular cli on your system. [This might help you](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5955#issuecomment-320273493)

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil yes that's true, but This issue I'm facing was with CLI 6.1.1, downgrading to 6.0.8 corrected everything. Thanks!!